# What did Anakin Skywalker win in winning the Boonta Eve Classic pod race?

Tags: star-wars

In *The Phantom Menace* Anakin Skywalker participated in the Boonta Eve Classic, a pod race on Tatooine. After winning the race did Anakin receive anything from the race's hosts, the Hutts, i.e. a purse or any other sort of winnings?

Answer (score 23):

Anakin was going to win money from the race through Qui-Gon's bargaining, but Qui-Gon essentially traded the money for the parts to repair their ship. He also won the [Boonta Cup](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Boonta_Cup), though it is unclear whether this was an actual cup (like the NHL's Stanley Cup), or merely the name of the prize money. Personally, the only thing he actually received was his freedom, and that too was more a result of Qui-Gon's bargaining.

From the Episode I film script:

> **WATTO**
>                            So, you supply the Pod and the entry 
>                            fee; I supply the boy. ***We split the winnings fifty-fifty, I think***.
>
> **QUI-GON**
>                            Fifty-fifty!?! If it's going to be 
>                            fifty-fifty, I suggest you front the 
>                            cash for the entry. If we win, ***you 
>                            keep all the winnings***, minus the 
>                            cost of the parts I need... If we 
>                            lose, you keep my ship.             *WATTO thinks about this. ANAKIN tries not to be nervous.*
>
> **QUI-GON**
>                            Either way, you win.

Additionally Anakin's Podracer was sold to Sebulba after the race, providing money that they gave to Shmi Skywalker.

Comment: As @Xantec notes, Anakin was a slave at the time of his participation in the race. Anakin himself would never have directly received any winnings, aside from side bets he may have placed. All the winnings went to Watto first, as the slave owner and the person who registered the entry.

Comment: Right, but *through Qui-Gon*, the group was going to get some of the winnings (which they essentially traded for parts).

Comment: I edited out all the irrelevant script lines and bolded the important ones.

Comment: Thanks @DVK! I wasn't sure if that would be helpful or not so I left them in

Answer (score 7):

Anakin Skywalker was a slave when he participated in the race. It is unlikely he personally won anything. On a side note, he did secure his own freedom in winning, due to the bet between Qui-Gon Jinn and Watto.

Comment: ok thank you i thought he won money or something

Comment: @Brandon I may be wrong, in which case I am sure someone more intimate with the canon will correct me in another answer.

Comment: Watto, on the other hand, may have won quite a bit.  But he bet against Anakin with more than just the Jedi, so I believe his losses outstripped his gains.

Comment: ok thanks im doing this movie for a project and i didnt think he won anything except the price of become a jedi

Comment: @Chad In this case Watto was the sponsor. See SSumner's answer, where Qui-Gon convinces Watto to front the entry fee.

Comment: @Chad Qui-Gon's party being entitled to winnings, which didn't include Anakin at that time, is not the same as Anakin being entitled to winnings. Qui-Gon splitting winnings 50/50 with Watto never included Anakin getting anything. Anakin being freed and leaving the planet doesn't apply to the OP, since that asks for what Anakin would have directly received from winning the race, not what benefits he received from Qui-Gon's machinations.

Comment: @Xantec - I never said that it did... this answer seems to imply that the reason that Anakin was not entitled to it was because he was a slave.  The reason he was not entitled was because he did not have any stake that would have entitled him to prize money.  And cannon does not support the implication that you make that slaves can not win any private property.

Comment: @Chad Mmm, conceded.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are referring to the wagers and such surrounding the race, but I think you're asking about whether there was any prize for winning the race itself, or if it was just a prop for wagers. The only canon reference to any prize or award to the winner of the Boonta Eve Classic Podrace appeared in the novelization of *Episode III*:

> Not because of the overwhelming odds, or the danger he was in; he didn't care about odds, and he didn't think of himself as being in any particular danger. A few wings of droid fighters didn't much scare a man who'd been a Podracer since he was six, and had **won the Boonta Cup** at nine. Who was, in fact, the only human to ever finish a Podrace, let alone 
>   win one.

(Emphasis mine.)